# SQL SELECT FROM: Inquiry

Tags: sql

I have a table with multiple fields for address, such as address_line_1, address_line_2, etc.

Is there any way that I can use a WHERE clause across multiple fields at once, without having to use an OR/AND statement?

For example:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM FIN_LIVE.CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES 
 WHERE SYS_ADDRESS_1, SYS_ADDRESS_2, SYS_ADDRESS_3 = 'data'
```

Comment: Why don't you want AND/OR statement?

Comment: @Tony: I can understand not wanting to use `OR`s - they can be expensive.

Comment: Is this separate lines of an address? .. perhaps you'd like to CONCAT_WS() the address fields and compare that to data. Examples of what your data looks like would help a lot to enable people here to give you the most useful and accurate advice.

Comment: Code Duck, I think you may be on to something there.  I essentially need to find a given address (such as 123 Green St.) within my table, but 123 Green St. could be in 1 of 4 separate address fields, each representing an address line.  Sometimes customers put their name on line 1, or the actual street address, so there is no consistency, and I have no control over this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure you'll have to use AND/OR

HOWEVER, maybe this is a sign to change your data structure.  Are you saying that there are 3 addresses, and any one of them could be 123 Main Street?

In that case, perhaps you need to pull address data out to a separate table.

Comment: Agreed, this sounds like a strange situation that probably should be recognized as a code smell, or a schema smell, if you wish.

Comment: @Alison R.: It's common to have at least three address lines for a mailing address.  The first line could be Rural Route (RR), or a "care of" (noted as c/o), second could be apt/suite number if separate from the street address.  There's no consistent format - dunno if any of the above applies to outside of Canada/US.

Comment: Correct.  But based on the initial query, he's asking if any of the three fields contain 'data'  I took that mean, do any of the lines contain '123 Main Street' Our addresses in our internal DB have line 1 for street #, line 2 for anything you mentioned there.  But we don't keep a 'home address' 'work address' and 'school address'  that's what I wanted to make sure wasn't happening here.

Comment: OMG Ponies has it right.  There are 4 lines we provide for an address, and the format is not consistent.  Sometimes a customer's line 1 will be the company name, or a subdivision, or a contact's name and sometimes it will be the exact address.

Comment: Ah, in that case then, ignore my comment.

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll need to use AND/OR.

```
SELECT * 
FROM FIN_LIVE.CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES 
WHERE SYS_ADDRESS_1 = 'data'
    AND SYS_ADDRESS_2 = 'data'
    AND SYS_ADDRESS_3 = 'data'
```

Comment: That would mean that the same value would have to be present in all three columns.  Depends on the data, but line addresses are rarely duplicated.

Comment: Yes, but what else could the OP be implying with that clause?

Comment: He could be implying an OR condition. So for example, if someone is at 123 Maple Drive, that might be in line 1, line 2, or line 3 of the address depending on how they entered it.

Comment: Ahh, true. So it's like a game of database column whack-a-mole. ;)

Answer edited to include the possibility of "OR." At any rate, we've got an XY problem here. http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341

Answer (score 1):

In `MySQL` with `MyISAM`, you can create a `FULLTEXT` index

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX fx_customeraddresses_123 ON FIN_LIVE.CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES (SYS_ADDRESS_1, SYS_ADDRESS_2, SYS_ADDRESS_3)
```

and issue this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    FIN_LIVE.CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES
WHERE   MATCH(SYS_ADDRESS_1, SYS_ADDRESS_2, SYS_ADDRESS_3) AGAINST ('+data')
```

, which will return all records with the word `data` in any of the fields.

You can even query it without the index:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    FIN_LIVE.CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES
WHERE   MATCH(SYS_ADDRESS_1, SYS_ADDRESS_2, SYS_ADDRESS_3) AGAINST ('+data' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

, but this will be much slower.

If you are looking for *exact* match in any of three fields, you may use this syntax:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    FIN_LIVE.CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES
WHERE   'data' IN (SYS_ADDRESS_1, SYS_ADDRESS_2, SYS_ADDRESS_3)
```

(works in all major databases).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid multiple `AND` statements to only enter the criterion, i.e. `SYS_ADDRESS_1 = 'data'`, once, you could always do:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM FIN_LIVE.CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES 
 WHERE 
    SYS_ADDRESS_1 = SYS_ADDRESS_2 
    AND SYS_ADDRESS_2 = SYS_ADDRESS_3 
    AND SYS_ADDRESS_3 = 'data'
```

I'm only pondering why you would want to exclude something as elementary as an `AND` operator?  I don't think I'm alone in that!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a row where any one of the columns match then you could do something like this, but it would be horribly inefficient compared to the simple OR statements.

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
     Customer_Addresses
WHERE
     '|*|' + sys_address_1 + '|*|' + sys_address_2 + '|*|' + sys_address_3 + '|*|' LIKE '%|*|' + @search_string + '|*|%'
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to turn this into an AND statement :)